# Does Thermald for Ubuntu work with AMD processors?

Tags: 14.04, overheating

I installed `tlp` and `thermald` to avoid overheating on my laptop, but I don't know if `thermald` is only for Intel processors or it will work the same with AMD processors.

I have an AMD A8 2.00 GHz and R5 Graphics and have three Operating Systems installed: Windows 10, Ubuntu (recently installed) and Elementary OS.

Comment: @andrew-46: Review [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/716189/revisions) etc...  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023, `thermald` will fail to run on modern AMD processors. Attempting to run `thermald` on AMD Ryzen 5000 processors, for example, will fail with this error from the daemon:

```
thermald: Unsupported cpu model or platform
```

To answer the OP's question, `thermald` no longer supports modern AMD processors.

According to an issue filed on `thermald`'s GitHub page concerning support for AMD processor, [the issue was closed with this message](https://github.com/intel/thermal_daemon/issues/383#issuecomment-1366862340):

> There is no AMD CPU support.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

According to `apt-cache show thermald`, `thermald`'s home page is  https://github.com/01org/thermal_daemon. That GitHub project [merged some code fixing things on several AMD processors](https://github.com/01org/thermal_daemon/pull/38), which implies it is supposed to work on AMD processors.